# STORM/TH rebus solving

Tags: visual, rebus

There is a rebus as follows. Can you find out what it says?

[image: storm|th]

Answer (score 8):

It is:

> Thunderstorm. Th + under + storm

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Thunderstorm? The Th is Under the Storm? lol